# What is this pointer type and how to use it?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

okay so i have come across this pointer type and i tried to use it in my code but i get a warning from the compiler saying its in incompatible pointer type

this is the type

`data_type (*i)[j]` with `i` being the variable name
and `j` being the size of the pointer

for example if you want the pointer to be as size of 4 ints you would declare

`int (*i)[4]` and then you would need to assign an array of 4 ints

```
i = &s[4]
```

however when i try to assign it, i get a warning from compiler saying `incompatible type`

so what seems to be the problem here? and how do i use it correctly?

Comment: is `s` an array? Could you give us the declaration of `s`?

Comment: c gibberish says declare i as pointer to array 4 of int

Comment: i think wat u r trying to do is `int s[4]; i = s;`

Comment: yes s is an array int s[4]

Comment: let me add that because brackets were used for i (*i) its not an array of pointers , in case people mistake that

Answer (score 6):

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) tells us that it is:

> ```
> int (*i)[4]
> ```
>
> declare i as pointer to array 4 of int

So, we can use it like this:

```
int arr[4];
int (*i)[4] = &arr;
```

Or, with heap allocated memory:

```
int (*j)[4] = malloc(sizeof(int[4]));
```

Comment: compiler still gives me a warning even when i tried i = &arr or i = arr for incompatible type

Comment: this is the parts of my code relative to this 

#define S 14
int arr3[S]={3,4,21,215,56,1,77,65,4,23,23,23,452,2};
thats my array

and this is my declaration

 int i,(*j)[S];

 j = &arr;

Comment: @hopjoppe5: Well, you created `arr3` and then assigned `arr` to `j`. `arr3` and `arr` are different names. But that being said, I can't reproduce your warning. http://ideone.com/iUUQoP

Answer (score 3):

`int (*i)[4];` declares `i` to be a pointer to an array of `4` `int`s. You said `s` is an array of `4` `int`

```
int s[4];
```

assignment

```
i = &s[4];
```

is wrong because `&s[4]` is the address of memory block just past the array and is of type `int *`. Generally arrays decay into pointer to its first element but in case of as an operand of unary `&` operator it doesn't decay and therefore `&s` gives the address of array `s` which is of type `int (*)[4]`.

```
i = &s;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `j` is variable, then I'd recommend to use `std::vector` instead and take a reference to the container rather than a pointer:

```
std::vector<int> i(j);
auto& i_ref = i;
```

If `j` is a constant expression, I'd still avoid using C-style arrays and use `std::array` instead, and still take only a reference:

```
constexpr std::size_t j = 4;
std::array<int, j> i;
auto& i_ref = i;
```

Comment: yes i am aware of vectors but for this particular code i need to use a pointer to an array of size i

Comment: @hopjoppe5 May I ask why?

Comment: well i have some data in an array which i want to specifically access , pixel information that i am storing and rendering to screen, and i need to set the scope of how much of that data in the array i want to access without over stepping any bounds and this was the perfect solution , a pointer to an array of size n, this keeps things within the range i want it and then i can change to another set of pixels within the array when i need to which can be quiet often

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int s[4];
```

declares `s` to be array of `4` `int`s.

Using the expression `s[4]` (after `s` had been defined) would evaluated to the 5th element of `s` (an `int`).

As `s` only has `4` elements, doing so is "illegal" and provokes undefined behaviour of the program.

So to assign to `int(*i)[4]` the address of `s` do:

```
 i = &s;
```

If using C99 or later to initialise `i` without declaring `s` you might also do:

```
i = &(int[4]){0};
```